# How to login to yahoo via Selenium python (tried multiple solutions)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to login to my yahoo account via selenium. I'm simply learning at this point and have made programs for different websites in order to get more comfortable with Selenium overall.

I'm now trying to login to Yahoo and I haven't been able to figure it out.

URL: https://login.yahoo.com/

I've tried doing:

```
yahoologin1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "#login-username"))).sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com")

yahoologin1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-username"))).sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com")

yahoologin1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='login-username']"))).sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com")

yahoologin1 = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]"))).sendKeys("tester@yahoo.com")
```

Anything that I'm particularly missing? Would appreciate if someone told me *how* to get this login to work. Rather have that than a simple copy paste of code :) Thank you!

I've done some further testing and it works when on the main tab. However, I am opening a new tab with the yahoo login page it doesn't work. Do I have to do something differently to type on a new tab?

Comment: What error message or unexpected result are you getting?

Comment: nothing, it's as if it doesn't find it.

Comment: ```try:
    loginYahoo = WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "/html[1]/body[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/form[1]/div[2]/input[1]")))

except TimeoutException:
    print("couldn't login to yahoo")```

It prints out the TimeoutException

Answer (score 1):

I used another approach without `WebDriverWait` to solve, hope it helps.

```
from selenium import webdriver

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920x1080")
browser = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', chrome_options=chrome_options)

# Opening yahoo page in a new tab
browser.execute_script("window.open('https://login.yahoo.com/');")
# Switch to new tab
browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])
# Selecting login-username and putting email
browser.find_element_by_id('login-username').send_keys('tester@yahoo.com')
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thank you! I have actually managed to get yahoo to sign in now when I load up a blank program. However, it seems that when I open a new tab with the yahoo login page, it cannot fill it out then. Any ideas why? Doesn't selenium autofocus on the new tab?

Comment: When you open a new tab, it needs be selected to selenium using `browser.switch_to.window(browser.window_handles[-1])`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample script.

```
url = "https://login.yahoo.com/"
# Step 1 -navigate to the AUT
driver.get(url)
print ("Step 1 - Done")
# Step 2 - Enter the username
#wait for the user name to be displayed
userName = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'input#login-username')))
userName.send_keys("used css")
# Step 3 - click on Next
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='login-signin']").click()
# Step 4 - Enter password
passWord = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input[name='password']")))
passWord.send_keys("password")
# Step 5 - Click on Sign in
driver.find_element_by_id("login-signin").click()
```

Here is how you can do the script development quick and effectively.

- Keep a break point after browser navigated to url
  [image]
- Get the element xpath using chrome devtools, refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) to how to get test and get the xpath
- Go to Console > click on `show python prompt`  to open the interactive console
  [image]
- Enter the code here and hit enter to check if that line works when you place it in your script
  [image][image]
- Make any necessary change and confirm the step works
  [image]
- Copy paste the step from interactive console to script
  [image]