# Unable to locate element - multiple element seem to have similar and minimal info and I can't find either correctly

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to extract some attributes from an element on a website but I am getting Unable to find element error. The element doesn't have much info in it to search, apart from the attributes, and the one that I want will change every time.

I was initially converting the HTML to text and then regex searching the text to get what I want. Now I'm trying to make it a bit more elegant.

**I have tried:**
 `browser.find_element_by_name("Status")`

- to search text attribute (I know this is wrong)
  `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@class='copySource']")`
- and a bunch of other variations
  `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//element[@attribute='Device Status:']")`

plus some other stuff.

using this, with `find all elements`, returned a blank list without an error.
    `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='class']")`

**The code I am trying to search:**

```
<td>
    <label class="copySource">Device Registration Status:</label>
</td>
<tr>
    <td>
        <label class="copySource">Device Status:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <span class="copySource copyEndLine">operational</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to extract the attribute in the last element, the word "operational" (this word changes). Getting error (or something similar to):

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: 
{"method":"xpath","selector":"//element[@attribute='Device Status:']"}
```

Comment: Check if the table is there in Iframe. Usually it should work with `td span.copyEndLine` css locator if the element is there in the main window.

Comment: Na no iframes there

Comment: Found the issues - needed to drill down to specify a more accurate xpath. Did this buy copying the xpath from chrome and then pasting somewhere else. I am quite new ad didnt know i could do this. Solved! thanks for your help everyone

Comment: Glad you are able to make it. Check my answer on [how to work with the xpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909). This might give you some tips and helping hand to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".copyEndLine").text
```

You might try to add a wait condition before getting the text of the element, something like "wait for element present" because maybe it is not yet loaded when you are interacting with it.

Comment: na no luck. tried element and get the same, "no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".copyEndLine"}"
Change it to elements and get an empty list [ ]
And tried extending the wait time right out and still no luck

Comment: Is the HTML code you posted inside of an iframe by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

To extract the text **operational** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "tr td>span.copySource copyEndLine"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//label[@class='copySource' and text()='Device Status:']//following::td[1]/span[@class='copySource copyEndLine']"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this happens, when there are components with similar name/tags.

Can you try: `browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[@class='class']")[0]` or any other index; based on the count of similar components on the page.

Also if you could share the url of page you are trying, it would be helpful.

Comment: unable to im afraid, secure internal company site

Answer (score 0):

The relevant XPath expression would be something like:

```
//label[text()='Device Status:']/ancestor::tr/descendant::*[contains(@class,'EndLine')]
```

where:

- `ancestor::tr` - selects the relevant table [tr tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_tr.asp) which is the [ancestor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/ancestor) for the current element
- `descendant::*[contains(@class,'EndLine')]` - looks for a [descendant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) (child or grandchild) which [`class` attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_class.asp) contains `EndLine` via XPath [contains() function](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Demo:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
browser.find_elements_by_cssselector(".copySource.copyEndLine")
```

If the element is inside a frame you have to switch to the frame, you can use this:

```
driver.switchTo().frame("FrameName");
```