# Trying to find text element in a span

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am coding a selenium webdriver test in Java. I need the test to click on a "Yes" button in chrome that does not have an id or name.
I cannot find the element to click on the button that only has "Yes" as its unique identifier. There is also a "No" button.

I have tried to find the WebElement using xpath, classname and I have tried findElements function. Nothing succeeds.

This is the HTML:

```
<span class="ui-btn-inner">
<span class="ui-btn-text popup-anchor-text">Yes</span>
</span>
```

I have tried:

```
WebElement yesBtn = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-btn-text popup-anchor-text']/span"));

WebElement yesBtn = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//span[.='Yes']"));

WebElement yesBtn = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Yes')]"));

WebElement yesBtn = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='ui-btn-text popup-anchor-text' and span='Yes']"));

WebElement yesBtn = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui-btn-text popup-anchor-text' and span='Yes']"));

yesBtn.click();

List<WebElement> yesBtn = browser.findElements(By.className("ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-up-a"));

yesBtn.get(0).click();
```

Error message:
NoSuchElementException; no such element. Unable to locate element.

Comment: Have you tried using the browser developer tools to select the xpath?

Comment: check if the span exist in another window, as it's saying `popup` in the class name.

Comment: The span does not exist in another window. I tried using the browser development tool in Chrome. I haven't found a good resource. They all just say search for xpath in Elements pane1 or $() in console panel. Nothing comes back for either.

Comment: right click on the element and hit `Inspect` in the context menu (last option), after opening the dev tools. That should point you to the element. Then try the xpath as shown in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)

Comment: how about Browser.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Yes')]"));

Comment: @supputuri  That worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The correct XPath locator would be:

```
//span[text()='Yes']
```

Just in case you can go for [`normalize-space()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space):

```
//span[normalize-space()='Yes']
```

If this doesn't help:

1. Make sure that the span doesn't belong to an [iframe](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), otherwise you will have to [switch to the iframe](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--) before attempting to locate the element.

   ```
   driver.switchTo().frame("your-frame");
   ```
2. Make sure to use [WebDriverWait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) class just in case the element is not immediately available so WebDriver would perform several find attempts with polling interval

   ```
   new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[text()='Yes']")));
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try out `//span[@class='ui-btn-inner']/descendant::span[contains(text(), 'Yes')]`. It should help out.