# How can I select below element in Selenium Java Web Driver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-chromedriver

Well I have below code

```
<button class="jobs-search-box__submit-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 ml2" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-689="689">Search</button>
```

I want to find this element in selenium and perform click action. I tried several options like by class, xpath, name, text, contains but nothing worked. 
Can someone guide me here?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search']")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("jobs-search-box__submit-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 ml2")).click();
driver.findElement(By.className("//*[@id=\"ember689\"]/button")).click();
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Search")).click();
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it say the button is not found? I presume you see it on screen? Because the xpath seems right according to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/2696/selenium-how-to-identify-the-button-webelement. I don't see an id or a link, so I would not expect the last two to work.

Comment: and by class name seems not to like three classes, see https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1480

Comment: Have you checked if the xpath `//button[contains(.,'Search']` is pointing to the right element in the [chrome dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)?

Comment: By.cssSelector(".jobs-search-box__submit-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--3.ml2") according to https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1480

Comment: @supputuri well //button[contains(.,'Search'] this does not point to any element. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: a closing right parenthesis? so //button[contains(.,'Search')]

Comment: @JeremyKahan: Yes it turned out to be missing right parenthesis. :|

Comment: Given that it fixed the problem, is it possible to accept the answer?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize what was in the comments. Each locator had something off.

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search']")
```

was missing a parenthesis and needed to be:

```
By.xpath("//button[contains(.,'Search')]")
```

Meanwhile, because By.className expects a single className

```
By.className("jobs-search-box__submit-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 ml2")
```

also does not work. (see [github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1480](http://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1480) 
but could as:

```
By.cssSelector(".jobs-search-box__submit-button.artdeco-button.artdeco-button--3.ml2")
```

Also

```
By.className("//*[@id=\"ember689\"]/button")
```

refers to an id not presented (Also, I'm not sure, but I think would need to be by xpath).

```
By.linkText("Search")
```

does not work because there is no tag `a` and so no hyperlink.

In Protractor this is much simpler because you would just say `by.buttonText('Search')`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same things by using javascript. kindly find the below example of code:

```
//Creating the JavascriptExecutor interface object by Typecasting       
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;

WebElement button =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='jobs-search-box__submit-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 ml2']"));

//Perform Click on LOGIN button using JavascriptExecutor        
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", button);
```

I hope it will work on your case.

Note: **Make sure your element will be static.**

Answer (score 0):

The correct XPath locator would be:

```
//button[text()='Search']
```

If you won't be able to locate it using the above query, make sure that:

1. The button doesn't belong to and [`<iframe>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp), if this is the case - you will have to change the context using [switchTo() function](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html#switchTo--)
2. The element is present in DOM, i.e. the page has been loaded fully. It's better to use [Explicit Wait](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-waits) for element location/interaction like:

   ```
   WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[text()='Search']")));
   ```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)

Answer (score 0):

Try with These two hope it works,

1.) Using Contains

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Search')]")));
```

2.) Using CSS

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.jobs-search-box__submit-button artdeco-button artdeco-button--3 ml2")));

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button.contains('Search')")));
```

If does not work let me know i'll provide another Solution.