# How evaluate an xpath expression against an html document?

Tags: xpath

Are there any tools that will let me see what the XPath expression is of a given node in an html document?  Im using Visual Studio 2017 and Notepad++ 7.7

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)

Comment: Awesome, didnt even think of using the browser console.  thanks