# NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

My ultimate goal is to simply login but there's 2 problem:

1. My code is unable to detect the ID to input email/password
2. The random characters in ID value keeps changing (id=login-email_**k9et69del**)

Your assistant will be greatly appreciated!

```py
#from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#create Chrome session
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://www.jetblue.com/signin')

#login
#wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.id, "emailLabel")));

username = driver.find_element_by_id("email").send_keys("xxx@gmail.com")

password = driver.find_element_by_id("Password").send_keys("xx")
```

[screenshot inspect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGhhd.png)

Comment: That doesn't look like java code to me.

Comment: Also this isn't a question. You dumped your code and said "this doesn't work". What would be a manual way to find that input element?

Comment: try with xpath with partial text matching on id attribute.

Comment: @Sureshmani thank you! xpath seems to do the job!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Id's that you are using are not correct.
[image]

You can use the below locators.

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='email']").send_keys("email goes here")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[type='password']").send_keys ("password goes here")
```

You can check if the locators is correct in the browser dev tools. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) post to know how to work with dev tools in browser dev tools.

Comment: Although, only the password field works with your code, I was able to get what im looking for from the the post that you link! Thanks youre awesome!

Comment: what about the email field, are you getting any error?

Comment: I was getting an NoSuchElementException error so I used xpath instead `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@type='email']").send_keys(user)`

Comment: I think script might be trying to send email before the field loaded on the page. You can explicitly wait for email element using  `WebDriverWait` and `ExpectedConditions`.

Comment: Trying to use both parameter above but it doesn't work.. `WebDriverWait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='email']"))).send_keys(user)`

Comment: try with `WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='email']"))).send_keys(user)`.

Comment: Yup that works~! Thanks a lot! Do you mind if I contact you if I have anymore questions?