# Selenium unable to find input text field within fieldset

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

I am having problems with selenium finding the input text field - 'billing-address__line-1 
The code i used is -

```java
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//fieldset[.//input[@id='billing-address__line-1']]"))
```

HTML source

```
<body>
<div id="app-root">
<div class="">
<div class="c-navigation" role="banner">
<section class="app-checkout">
<section class="tickets-summary">
<div class="page-content page-content--mobile-full-width">
<div class="checkout-form">
<div class="app-checkout-form-feedback"/>
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="checkout-form-passengers">
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="checkout-form-contact-details">
<form method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" id="checkout-form-payment">
<div class="checkout-form-panel checkout-form-panel--no-padding app-payment" id="checkout-form-fieldset-payment">
<fieldset>
<legend class="checkout-form-panel--padding-fix checkout-form-panel__header h3">Payment</legend>
<div class="checkout-form-panel--padding-fix">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-medium-12 payment-switch__toggle">
<div>
<div class="billing-address" id="checkout-form-fieldset-billing-address">
<fieldset>
<legend class="h3 checkout-form-panel__header">Billing address</legend>
<div class="feedback-message" id="checkout-fieldset-feedback-billing-address">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 input__wrap input__wrap--error">
<label for="billing-address__line-1">Address line 1</label>
<input type="text" id="billing-address__line-1" name="billing-address" data-type="line1" maxlength="35" value=""/>
<div class="input__feedback">Just let us know your address</div>
</div>
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 last input__wrap">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 input__wrap">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 last input__wrap">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 input__wrap">
<div class="checkout-form-panel__col-from-small-6 last input__wrap">
```

Error Message

> Error - Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to
>   locate element:
>   {"method":"xpath","selector":".//fieldset[.//input[@id='billing-address__line-1']]"

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: Error - Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":".//fieldset[.//input[@id='billing-address__line-1']]"}

Comment: Why do you have to use complex xpath. if the id is unique, you can directly use that to locate the element. driver.findElement(By.id("billing-address__line-1"))

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use id to find WebElement. Try:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("billing-address__line-1"))
```

And if you want to use xpath, it should be used as below:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//fieldset//input[@id='billing-address__line-1']")
```

Answer (score 0):

To send a *character sequence* within the *input text field* associated with the `<label>` **Address line 1** you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *cssSelector*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='billing-address__line-1']")).sendKeys("learnerhere");
  ```
- *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='billing-address__line-1']")).sendKeys("learnerhere");
  ```