# Python Selenium: Grab value from TD with on ID but

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm trying to grab the value of a TD with no ID but the TR has a class. The other issue is there are multiple tables on the same page, also with no ID. Please see below:

[image]

I need to get the value for Machine ID and Total Memory that is underlined in the screenshot above

Here's what I tried:

```
 browser.switch_to.default_content()
 frames = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('frame')
 browser.switch_to.frame(frames[1])

 value1 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr[@class='staticProp']/td[1]")).get_attribute("value")
 value2 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr[@class='staticProp']/td[2]")).get_attribute("value")
 value3 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr[@class='staticProp']/td[3]")).get_attribute("value")
 value4 =      browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr[@class='staticProp']/td[4]")).get_attribute("value")
 value5 = browser.find_element_by_xpath(("//tr[@class='staticProp']/td[5]")).get_attribute("value")



 print(value1)
 print(value2)
 print(value3)
 print(value4)
 print(value5)
```

But I get none as the results.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

UPDATE

Here's an additional screenshot. Is the : the problem?

[image]

Thanks,

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you done any debugging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are in the correct frame and then you can try with the below xpaths.

**Machine ID:**

```
//td[.='Machine ID']/parent::tr/td[last()]
```

**Total Memory:**

```
//td[.='Total Memory']/parent::tr/td[last()]
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no results. I added an additional screenshot.

Comment: First try those xpaths in chrome devtools and see if the xpaths working. Then check if you are pointing to right frame.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) post, this will give detailed information how to check xpath/css in chrome devtools.