# I need help interacting with an HTML element using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use Python Selenium to click on an HTML web element using Internet Explorer 11, can't use XPATH.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import time

manage = driver.find_element_by_id("__tab_ctl00_PageBody,
_TabContainer1_Managetab")

manage.click()
```

And here is the HTML I'm trying to interact with:

```
<SPAN id=__tab_ctl00_PageBody_TabContainer1_Managetab 
class=ajax__tab_tab>Manage</SPAN>
```

I'm getting a NoSuchElementException.

Comment: there is a comma

Answer (score 0):

*Try to add time time.sleep(3) before manage and fix your element.*

```
time.sleep(3)
manage = driver.find_element_by_id("__tab_ctl00_PageBody_TabContainer1_Managetab")
```

Comment: if he removes the comma it might work, later he can sleep

Answer (score 0):

The core issue is, your id locator is not correct (comma and space is the culprit). In CSS comma have it's own meaning. So your id should be

```
__tab_ctl00_PageBody_TabContainer1_Managetab
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) to see how you can check the locator if it's working correctly.
Always use Explicit wait rather static wait (sleep) as shown below, by that way the script will move on to the next steps when element met the conditioin.

**Imports needed:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Your code should be (here we are waiting for the element for max of 30 seconds).

```
manage = WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'__tab_ctl00_PageBody_TabContainer1_Managetab')))
```

Comment: I tried your solution supputuri,  I got a Timeout exception.

Comment: check if the element is present in the iframe.

Comment: There are no Iframes on the page.  Just AJAX

Comment: Can you please manually check if the element is located when you use the `id` from the answer once the page is loaded. If it's identifying then we can try increasing the time from 30 seconds to 120.

Comment: It's not.  Getting NameError name 'manage' is not defined.  From what I've read, AJAX elements are not in the source code they are dynamically acquired, so it's difficult to parse them.