# PYTHON SELENIUM Is there a way how to upload photo by sendkeys in this website?

Tags: python, selenium, upload, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to upload photo without the windows popup. So i was trying to use driver.find_element_by_id("IdOf**Input**TypeFile").send_keys("/image.png") . The problem is i can't find input element, here the screen shots of the html code and also i've found 2 hidden inputs i don't know what's for. Thank you!  ([Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKFsF.png)) ([Screenshot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOg3z.png)) - ([Screenshot3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEWOz.png)) - ([Screenshot4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXSMM.png)) - ([Screenshot5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EtKn.png)) - ([Screenshot6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vjPM.png)) - ([Screenshot7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBcSs.png)) - ([The 2 hidden inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHi16.png))

Comment: Seems to be the file upload form does not have `input type of file`. You can try `//input[@type='file']` xpath in the [dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) to see if there is any fileupload input filed exist on the page.

Comment: So there is no input filed on the page. The other approach would be using API to upload the file.

Comment: @supputuri i searched for it and found it !
Thank you !

Comment: You mean the `//input[@type='file']` worked?

Comment: @supputuri Yes! i just didn't know how to use it well in the first try. Now it's worked. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 0):

try `//input[@type='file']` xpath in the [dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) to see if there is any fileupload input filed exist on the page

```
//input[@type='file']
```

Comment: If you feel the issue is resolved, please [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this/any answer is/was helpful to you. Also [Upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) the answer for the benefit of the future readers