# Selenium check the button[svg]

Tags: selenium, python-3.6

I'am working on Selenium with Python. I write a code which is about Instagram like Bot. I achived this. I can login->enter the profile then like photos in order. But I want to check photo liked or unliked. If photo already like then go to next photo.

I can't get atrribute like button.

This is example of unliked photo:

```
<button class="wpO6b " type="button">
<svg aria-label="Like" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
    <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M34.3 3.5C27.2 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s-3.2-5.3-10.3-5.3C6.4 3.5.5 9.9.5 17.8s6.1 12.4 12.2 17.8c9.2 8.2 9.8 8.9 11.3 8.9s2.1-.7 
    11.3-8.9c6.2-5.5 12.2-10 12.2-17.8 0-7.9-5.9-14.3-13.2-14.3zm-1 29.8c-5.4 4.8-8.3 7.5-9.3 8.1-1-.7-4.6-3.9-9.3-8.1-5.5-4.9-11.2-9-11.2-15.6 0-6.2 4.6-
    11.3 10.2-11.3 4.1 0 6.3 2 7.9 4.2 3.6 5.1 1.2 5.1 4.8 0 1.6-2.2 3.8-4.2 7.9-4.2 5.6 0 10.2 5.1 10.2 11.3 0 6.7-5.7 10.8-11.2 15.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
    </path>
</svg>
```

This is example of liked photo

```
<button class="wpO6b " type="button">
<svg aria-label="Unlike" class="_8-yf5 " fill="#262626" height="24" viewBox="0 0 48 48" width="24">
    <path clip-rule="evenodd" d="M34.3 3.5C27.2 3.5 24 8.8 24 8.8s-3.2-5.3-10.3-5.3C6.4 3.5.5 9.9.5 17.8s6.1 12.4 12.2 17.8c9.2 8.2 9.8 8.9 11.3 8.9s2.1-.7 
    11.3-8.9c6.2-5.5 12.2-10 12.2-17.8 0-7.9-5.9-14.3-13.2-14.3zm-1 29.8c-5.4 4.8-8.3 7.5-9.3 8.1-1-.7-4.6-3.9-9.3-8.1-5.5-4.9-11.2-9-11.2-15.6 0-6.2 4.6-
    11.3 10.2-11.3 4.1 0 6.3 2 7.9 4.2 3.6 5.1 1.2 5.1 4.8 0 1.6-2.2 3.8-4.2 7.9-4.2 5.6 0 10.2 5.1 10.2 11.3 0 6.7-5.7 10.8-11.2 15.6z" fill-rule="evenodd">
    </path>
</svg>
```

How can I (get aria-label="Unlike") or (aria-label="Like" attribute ). Or is there any other solution?
Thank you

Comment: Were you able to get the element? If yes, then you have to use `element.get_attribute("aria-label")`. If you are looking for the element locating solution then  please share the svg parent info.

Comment: @supputuri Add them.

Comment: Try ` //button[normalize-space(@class)='wpO6b']/*[name()='svg']`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the xpath that you can use to find the button with Svg.

```
 //button[normalize-space(@class)='wpO6b']/*[name()='svg']
```

[image]

your code should be something like the below.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath(" //button[normalize-space(@class)='wpO6b']/*[name()='svg']")
print(ele.get_attribute('aria-label')
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you. but I have another problem. I can get "fill" attrubte like  "#262626" but "arial-label" tag return = "Option". Because it is dynamic value I think. Is there any solution for dynamic values?

Comment: check if it's pointing to the right element, you can check in [dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)

Comment: I dit it with using driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.fr66n > button > svg").get_attribute("aria-label") . Thanks man