# no such element: Unable to locate element python id

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to send_keys to this input :

```
<input id="textfield-1017-inputEl" data-ref="inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="search" placeholder="Find Bunker.." aria-hidden="false" aria-disabled="false" role="textbox" aria-invalid="false" aria-readonly="false" aria-describedby="textfield-1017-ariaStatusEl" aria-required="false" class="searchfield x-form-text x-form-text-default  x-form-empty-field x-form-empty-field-default" autocomplete="off" data-componentid="textfield-1017">
```

but I am always getting this error :

> Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="textfield-1017-inputEl"]"}
>     (Session info: chrome=80.0.3987.163)

I am using selenium in python , and this is the code I am using :

```
find_my_input = browser.find_element_by_id('textfield-1017-inputEl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
iframe= wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ext-gen1099")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)

element= WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "textfield-1017-inputEl")))
```

**Note :** please add below imports to your solution

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```

Comment: It was a nested iframe, I used your solution and it worked. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear that , would you kind enough to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) answer and hit upvote button from your end.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you wait for the element to be loaded using the explicit wait as shown below.

**Imports needed:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

change the code to the below.

```
find_my_input = WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"textfield-1017-inputEl")))
```

If element is present in the iframe then you have to switch to the iframe first and then access the element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('id/name goes here')
find_my_input = WebDriverWait(browser,30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,"textfield-1017-inputEl")))
```

Comment: I have received the following message :

TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: I even changed that 30s to 120s, but it's not working.

Comment: Do you see the element on the page? If, yes then the element might be present in an iframe. check if the element is pointing to the root html element or any iframe html using `//input[@id='textfield-1017-inputEl']/ancestor::html` in chrome devtools as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909)

Comment: it's is not an iframe, i got the following result :
<html id="ext-element-4" class="x-viewport">

Comment: whats the parent of `<html id="ext-element-4" class="x-viewport">`?

Comment: the parrent is :

`<iframe src="//website.com/" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" id="ext-gen1099">`

I tried using `browser.switch_to.frame('id/ext-gen1099')`, but I got this error :
`NoSuchFrameException: Message: id/ext-gen1099`

Comment: What should I do in case of there are many parents of this iframe ( 3 divs and 2 iframes) ?