# Find element with dynamic div?

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, element

Is It possible to find an element using `xpath` that has a dynamic `div`?

```
test = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/main[1]/div[HERE!]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]')
```

I must find this element that changes the `div[HERE!]` deppending of your action on the page

EDIT

Here's the outer HTML. `label` is the only unique part of it, and the numeric (91) is dynamic...

```
 <div class="group">
 <label>Tipo Benefício</label>
 <span><b class="numeric">91</b>AUXILIO DOENCA POR ACIDENTE DE TRABALHO
 </span></div>
```

Comment: Please share the relevant html, you don't have to use the absolute xpath and you can find them using the attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your help man, I'm new codding... I'v edited my question, hope you can help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below relative xpath to get the numeric value.

```
//div[@class='group']/b[@class='numeric']
```

Your code should be

```
test = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='group']/b[@class='numeric']")
print(test.text)
```

You can access the other elements as shown below

```
# label => //div[@class ='group']/label
# span  => //div[@class ='group']/span
```

You can refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909) to check your xpath/css locators are working as expected in chrome devtools.