# Error Message: no such element: Unable to locate element. How to rectify it?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

\Some more Codes

for url in tqdmn(mel.Url[:10], leave=False):

> driver.get(url)
> Url_With_Coordinates.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2"]'))

Here is the error message:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class="ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2"]"}
```

HTML Element:

```
<div jstcache="243" class="ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text gm2-body-2" jsan="7.ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text,7.gm2-body-2">Example, 431 St Michale Rd, New York 3004, United States</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the below line as `ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text` and `gm2-body-2` are 2 classes and you should always replace white space with `.` when you have multiple classes.

```
Url_With_Coordinates.append(driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div[class="ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text.gm2-body-2"]'))
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for the reply

Comment: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"div[class="ugiz4pqJLAG__primary-text.gm2-body-2"]"}

Comment: Can you please check if the locator is working in the chrome devtools. You can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55870609/is-there-a-way-to-learn-xpath-without-using-firebug-or-xpath-as-firefox-is-not-s/55870909#55870909